# Manually drawing a circle with a radial distance from center lat/lng using google maps ios sdk

Tags: ios, cocoa, google-maps-sdk-ios

I need to send lat/lng coordinates to a 3rd party API and it doesn't look like it's possible to extract lat/lng coordinates from a `GMSCircle`, so
I was thinking about generating an array of `CGPoints` and using `GMSProjection` to extract the location coordinates, however the radius needs to be exactly 1.5 miles; so with regard to the zoom level would I need to resort to something like this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7430/what-ratio-scales-do-google-maps-zoom-levels-correspond-to to calculate it?

Is there a better way to go about this? I feel like this would be a pretty common use case

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out, I ended up using the [GMSGeometryUtils](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/group___geometry_utils#ga8d6fb874513718f8325ebca9615b051e) `GMSGeometryOffset` function to get the offset from my origin and make a circle.

```
NSMutableArray *path = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D locationCoordinate = GMSGeometryOffset(location.coordinate, 2414.02, i*6);
    [path addObject:[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:locationCoordinate.latitude longitude:locationCoordinate.longitude]];
}
```